# 1989 S10 AC Compressor not working

Tags: chevrolet, ac, s10

I was wondering if someone could help me with my AC unit.I drive a 1989 S10 Blazer with a 4.3 L v6 TBI engine.. I changed the ac clutch 3 months ago because the clutch was on its way out. Now that summer is here, every time i switch on the AC , the compressor doesn't start. It keeps blowing regular vent air instead of cooled air. There used to be precipitation built on the accumulator but now there is none.

I am thinking this means the ac unit needs recharging but i want to make sure thats the case before i make any moves to fix it. Can anyone tell me how i can go about troubleshooting this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ensured the A/C clutch is working correctly?

Comment: It is spinning as expected. There used to be a whine every time i started the truck (like a supercharger ) but now it doesn't make that noise. Is there an another test i can do to check if the clutch is engaging?

Comment: Connect your 134a ac gauges and see if there is any pressure in the system, fill as needed.

Comment: What do you mean, "*It is spinning as expected*"? Are you saying the bearings are fine? I'm wondering if it the clutch is engaging or *can even engage*. If it doesn't, you'll get nothing. You can apply power directly to the clutch. In troubleshooting, always go back to the last thing you did and start there.

Comment: Even better, check for resistance at the coil terminals with a multimeter. It should be between 3 and 6 Ohms. That is to check if the coil actually works, without even trying to power it. Good place to begin without risking a pointless regas.